# What is Windows Application Packaging Project for?

Tags: uwp

When building my UWP project I am getting warning:
`This project uses the 'runFullTrust' capability. You should use the Windows Application Packaging Project to produce the store and sideload packages.`

Why should I use this project and how it will affect my publishing experience?

Comment: Why are you adding the runFullTrust capability in your app? The runFullTrust is generally used in desktop bridge applications, you can create the Windows Application Packaging Project to package your app and the project by default adds the 'runFullTrust' capability to your manifest.

Comment: I need runFullTrust to launch win32 executable in my app. I wonder why would I bother with packaging project, when I can just package my executable.

Comment: What does package my executable mean? Can you show more details about how you package your win32 executable?

Comment: I meant that why use packaging project, when I can package UWP app project (without separate project). I am only publishing to Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/resolve-submission-errors#desktop-application), it mentions

> If you plan to submit a package that contains both Win32 and UWP
>   binaries, make sure that you create that package by using the Windows
>   Packaging Project. If you create the package by using a UWP project template, you might not be able to submit that package to the Store or sideload it onto other PCs. Even if the package publishes successfully, it might behave in unexpected ways on the user's PC.

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to create Windows Application Packaging Project to package your app as Desktop bridge app. In that case, declaring the **fullTrustProcess** extension in the manifest of your Packaging project instead of UWP project. The **runFullTrust** capability will be added by default in your package manifest, so  you don't need to declare it again in your uwp app.

Desktop bridge app is acceptable for Microsoft Store, but when submitting, you will need to fill in some additional information and the store team will review your submission. After passing the review, the app will show in the store.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had no idea that Windows Packaging Project = Desktop bridge. This message was not clear for me because I have regular UWP app with win32 executable supporting one usecase.